# Initializing a pointer inside a class by means of the constructor

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to create a class with a pointer member in it and initialize that pointer when constructing an instance of the class, like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(int x): p(&x){}

    int getValueOfp() 
    {
        return *p;
    }

private:
    int* p;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int x=5;
    MyClass obj1(x);
    std::cout<<obj1.getValueOfp();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when I call `getValueOf()` the output I get is not the value of the variable that `p` is supposed to be pointing at (5 in this case, since it is supposed to be pointing at `x`). I have searched the web for a possible answer to this issue without any luck, could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong in here? (I'm working on Visual Studio Express, as you can see).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MyClass(int x) : p(&x) {}
```

Your parameter is passed by value, so a copy will be made. This copy is a temporary value that will expire by the end of the constructor body. So you're not initializing `p` with the address of the actual parameter, but merely a local *copy* of it. When you dereference the pointer later on, you won't find the actual value in it because the integer would have expired by then, which is Undefined Behavior. You'll need to pass your argument by *reference* so a copy is not performed:

```
MyClass(int& x) : p(&x) {}
//      ^^^^
```